# sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have several classes with the same relationship. For example:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    foonr = Column('foonr', Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar= Column('bar_code',String, ForeignKey('bar.bar_code'))
    bar_rel = relationship('Foo', back_populates='foo_rel')

class Bar(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    code = Column('bar_code', String, primary_key=True)
    foo_rel = relationship('Foo', uselist=False, back_populates=' bar_rel')
```

This is almost a copy-paste from: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html. However when I try to query an unrelated class (not Foo or Bar) in this example, I get following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
>   between parent/child tables on relationship ... - there are no foreign
>   keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are
>   associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a
>   'primaryjoin' expression.

Can someone explain this behaviour? Help me solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `relationship` in class `Foo` should be:

```
bar_rel = relationship('Bar', back_populates='foo_rel')
```